# Varnish not keeping cache for more than a few minutes

Tags: varnish

I am running a Magento 2 site that is going very slow because Varnish will not keep it's cache for more than a few minutes. Here is the default.vcl file:

```
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 6
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 6.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'SSL-OFFLOADED: https'

backend default {
    .host = "172.26.12.6";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    "172.26.12.6";
}

sub vcl_recv {

    if (req.restarts > 0) {
       set req.hash_always_miss = true;
    }

    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
    }

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }


    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED) {
        hash_data(req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED);
    }
    

    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        call process_graphql_headers;
    }
}

sub process_graphql_headers {
    if (req.http.Store) {
        hash_data(req.http.Store);
    }
    if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
        hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 604800s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (restart);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

When I load any page, it will take around 5-8 seconds for it to load. For the next 5-10 minutes, it will load in about 150ms. After about 10 minutes, it will go back to taking around 5-8 seconds to load and the cycle continues. I have it set to keep the cache for 1 week in the admin panel. It also has 3gb of memory to work with and will almost never use more than around 30mb of it.

I'm not sure what could be causing this. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE 1:

Here is the varnishlog when varnish had the page cached:

```
*   << Request  >> 73852     
-   Begin          req 73851 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1621443817.046353 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1621443817.046353 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       172.26.12.6 41170 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /exampleproduct.html
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      Host: example.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: example.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: 172.69.142.27
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 2601:204:dd00:94c:20c:29ff:fef6:270b, 172.69.142.27
-   ReqHeader      Ssl-Offloaded: 1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   ReqHeader      CF-IPCountry: US
-   ReqHeader      CF-RAY: 651ee64ff9455f88-SMF
-   ReqHeader      CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
-   ReqHeader      cache-control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   ReqHeader      upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-site: same-origin
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-user: ?1
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-dest: document
-   ReqHeader      referer: https://example.com/exampleproduct.html
-   ReqHeader      accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es-ES;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
-   ReqHeader      cookie: _gid=GA1.2.1875408680.1621020942; mage-messages=; cf_clearance=bbfb28e3e23443eceb422f7ee7f35f9fe10d7f1b-1621358137-0-150; form_key=nKb2t0FfKDugritm; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; PHPSESSID=nif7ckijs0ha
-   ReqHeader      CF-Connecting-IP: 2601:204:dd00:94c:20c:29ff:fef6:270b
-   ReqHeader      CDN-Loop: cloudflare
-   ReqHeader      cf-request-id: 0a272e45fd00005f8890abd000000001
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 2601:204:dd00:94c:20c:29ff:fef6:270b, 172.69.142.27
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 2601:204:dd00:94c:20c:29ff:fef6:270b, 172.69.142.27, 172.26.12.6
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /exampleproduct.html
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   Hit            530763 1209209.552413 259200.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_call       HIT
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 19 May 2021 16:57:06 GMT
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     Pragma: cache
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=1209600, public, s-maxage=1209600
-   RespHeader     Expires: Wed, 02 Jun 2021 16:57:03 GMT
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,ubmegamenu_group,ubmegamenu_item,cms_b_contact-numbers,cms_b_google_translate,cms_b_company-info,cms_b_customer-support,cms_b_contact-us,cat_p_1380,cat_p,cat_p_1923,cat_p_2270,cat_p_2281,cat_p_2287,cat_p_1920,cms_b_gtm_header,
-   RespHeader     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   RespHeader     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   RespHeader     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   RespHeader     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 73852 530763
-   RespHeader     Age: 390
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      Age: 390
-   RespUnset      Pragma: cache
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespUnset      Expires: Wed, 02 Jun 2021 16:57:03 GMT
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespUnset      Cache-Control: max-age=1209600, public, s-maxage=1209600
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,ubmegamenu_group,ubmegamenu_item,cms_b_contact-numbers,cms_b_google_translate,cms_b_company-info,cms_b_customer-support,cms_b_contact-us,cat_p_1380,cat_p,cat_p_1923,cat_p_2270,cat_p_2281,cat_p_2287,cat_p_1920,cms_b_gtm_header,
-   RespUnset      Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 73852 530763
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1621443817.046443 0.000089 0.000089
-   Filters        
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 35904
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1621443817.046527 0.000174 0.000085
-   ReqAcct        2365 0 2365 428 35904 36332
-   End
```

And here is the page about 10 minutes later when varnish did not have the page cached (I think it captured two requests, it's an active site):

```
*   << Request  >> 397487    
-   Begin          req 397486 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1621444231.047850 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1621444231.047850 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       172.26.12.6 58138 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /exampleproduct.html
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      Host: example.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: example.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: 172.69.142.57
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 2601:204:dd00:94c:20c:29ff:fef6:270b, 172.69.142.57
-   ReqHeader      Ssl-Offloaded: 1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   ReqHeader      CF-IPCountry: US
-   ReqHeader      CF-RAY: 651ef06b6a105ffa-SMF
-   ReqHeader      CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
-   ReqHeader      cache-control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   ReqHeader      upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-site: same-origin
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-user: ?1
-   ReqHeader      sec-fetch-dest: document
-   ReqHeader      referer: https://example.com/exampleproduct.html
-   ReqHeader      accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es-ES;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
-   ReqHeader      cookie: _gid=GA1.2.1875408680.1621020942; mage-messages=; cf_clearance=bbfb28e3e23443eceb422f7ee7f35f9fe10d7f1b-1621358137-0-150; form_key=nKb2t0FfKDugritm; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; PHPSESSID=nif7ckijs0ha
-   ReqHeader      CF-Connecting-IP: 2601:204:dd00:94c:20c:29ff:fef6:270b
-   ReqHeader      CDN-Loop: cloudflare
-   ReqHeader      cf-request-id: 0a2734971e00005ffa220b9000000001
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 2601:204:dd00:94c:20c:29ff:fef6:270b, 172.69.142.57
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 2601:204:dd00:94c:20c:29ff:fef6:270b, 172.69.142.57, 172.26.12.6
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /exampleproduct.html
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 397488 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1621444234.406568 3.358718 3.358718
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 19 May 2021 17:10:34 GMT
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     Pragma: cache
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=1209600, public, s-maxage=1209600
-   RespHeader     Expires: Wed, 02 Jun 2021 17:10:31 GMT
-   RespHeader     X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,ubmegamenu_group,ubmegamenu_item,cms_b_contact-numbers,cms_b_google_translate,cms_b_company-info,cms_b_customer-support,cms_b_contact-us,cat_p_1380,cat_p,cat_p_1923,cat_p_2270,cat_p_2281,cat_p_2287,cat_p_1920,cms_b_gtm_header,
-   RespHeader     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   RespHeader     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   RespHeader     X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   RespHeader     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 397487
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespUnset      Pragma: cache
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespUnset      Expires: Wed, 02 Jun 2021 17:10:31 GMT
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespUnset      Cache-Control: max-age=1209600, public, s-maxage=1209600
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,ubmegamenu_group,ubmegamenu_item,cms_b_contact-numbers,cms_b_google_translate,cms_b_company-info,cms_b_customer-support,cms_b_contact-us,cat_p_1380,cat_p,cat_p_1923,cat_p_2270,cat_p_2281,cat_p_2287,cat_p_1920,cms_b_gtm_header,
-   RespUnset      Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 397487
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1621444234.406603 3.358753 0.000035
-   Filters        
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 35904
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1621444234.406701 3.358851 0.000099
-   ReqAcct        2339 0 2339 428 35904 36332
-   End            
**  << BeReq    >> 397488    
--  Begin          bereq 397487 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1621444231.047964 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /exampleproduct.html
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
--  BereqHeader    Host: example.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: example.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: 172.69.142.57
--  BereqHeader    Ssl-Offloaded: 1
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
--  BereqHeader    CF-IPCountry: US
--  BereqHeader    CF-RAY: 651ef06b6a105ffa-SMF
--  BereqHeader    CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
--  BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
--  BereqHeader    upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
--  BereqHeader    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36
--  BereqHeader    accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-site: same-origin
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-mode: navigate
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-user: ?1
--  BereqHeader    sec-fetch-dest: document
--  BereqHeader    referer: https://example.com/exampleproduct.html
--  BereqHeader    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es-ES;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
--  BereqHeader    cookie: _gid=GA1.2.1875408680.1621020942; mage-messages=; cf_clearance=bbfb28e3e23443eceb422f7ee7f35f9fe10d7f1b-1621358137-0-150; form_key=nKb2t0FfKDugritm; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; PHPSESSID=nif7ckijs0ha
--  BereqHeader    CF-Connecting-IP: 2601:204:dd00:94c:20c:29ff:fef6:270b
--  BereqHeader    CDN-Loop: cloudflare
--  BereqHeader    cf-request-id: 0a2734971e00005ffa220b9000000001
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 2601:204:dd00:94c:20c:29ff:fef6:270b, 172.69.142.57, 172.26.12.6
--  BereqHeader    grace: none
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 397488
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  BackendOpen    33 default 172.26.12.6 8080 172.26.14.47 39730
--  BackendStart   172.26.12.6 8080
--  Timestamp      Bereq: 1621444231.048055 0.000091 0.000091
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1621444234.395396 3.347432 3.347342
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   200
--  BerespReason   OK
--  BerespHeader   Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
--  BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 19 May 2021 17:10:34 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
--  BerespHeader   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
--  BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
--  BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
--  BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=nif7ckijs0hadsu747olm449bh; expires=Wed, 19-May-2021 19:10:31 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=example.com; secure; HttpOnly
--  BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: form_key=nKb2t0FfKDugritm; expires=Wed, 19-May-2021 19:10:31 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=example.com; secure
--  BerespHeader   Pragma: cache
--  BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=1209600, public, s-maxage=1209600
--  BerespHeader   Expires: Wed, 02 Jun 2021 17:10:31 GMT
--  BerespHeader   X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,ubmegamenu_group,ubmegamenu_item,cms_b_contact-numbers,cms_b_google_translate,cms_b_company-info,cms_b_customer-support,cms_b_contact-us,cat_p_1380,cat_p,cat_p_1923,cat_p_2270,cat_p_2281,cat_p_2287,cat_p_1920,cms_b_gtm_header,
--  BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
--  BerespHeader   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
--  BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
--  BerespHeader   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
--  BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
--  TTL            RFC 1209600 10 0 1621444234 1621444234 1621444234 1622653831 1209600 cacheable
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
--  TTL            VCL 1209600 259200 0 1621444234 cacheable
--  BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=nif7ckijs0hadsu747olm449bh; expires=Wed, 19-May-2021 19:10:31 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=example.com; secure; HttpOnly
--  BerespUnset    Set-Cookie: form_key=nKb2t0FfKDugritm; expires=Wed, 19-May-2021 19:10:31 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=example.com; secure
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Filters        gunzip esi_gzip
--  BerespUnset    Content-Encoding: gzip
--  BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
--  Storage        malloc s0
--  Fetch_Body     2 chunked -
--  Gzip           G F E 477855 35904 80 287152 287162
--  Gzip           U F - 35893 477855 80 216112 287074
--  BackendReuse   33 default
--  Timestamp      BerespBody: 1621444234.406546 3.358582 0.011149
--  Length         35904
--  BereqAcct      2339 0 2339 1052 0 1052
--  End
```

These were both on the same product page. The front page doesn't really have a huge issue with load times, it's the product pages that are brutal. The cache could have expired sooner, I just waited 10 minutes between refreshes. The time where it was cached, the server response was 115ms and when not cached was 3.5 seconds.

UPDATE 2:

Here is varnishlog for Purge request:

```
*   << Request  >> 1451815   
-   Begin          req 1451814 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1621546852.088978 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1621546852.088978 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       172.26.12.6 44816 a0
-   ReqMethod      PURGE
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      X-Magento-Tags-Pattern: ((^|,)amasty_checkbox(,|$))
-   ReqHeader      Host: 172.26.14.47
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 172.26.12.6
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_acl        MATCH purge "172.26.12.6"
-   VCL_return     synth
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   Timestamp      Process: 1621546852.089046 0.000068 0.000068
-   RespHeader     Date: Thu, 20 May 2021 21:40:52 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 1451815
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespReason     Purged
-   VCL_call       SYNTH
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 242
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   Filters        
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1621546852.089096 0.000118 0.000050
-   ReqAcct        93 0 93 220 242 462
-   End
```

ANSWER:

With the help of Danila Vershinin, I figured out that one of Amasty's plugins was issuing a purge command every time someone accepted a TOS through their extension. I don't know why they are doing that, but I updated my default.vcl as shown below:

Original:

```
if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
```

Updated:

```
if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern !~ "amasty_checkbox") {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
```

I basically told varnish to ignore purge requests coming from "amasty_checkbox". Varnish is now holding page caches as expected and has been actively serving cached content for 16 hours as of writing this. Thanks to everyone for helping me solve this issue.

Comment: Hello @Eric Brown - I am facing similar issue, can you help me how you have logged those caches ? we tried using amasty warmer extension where i can see the cache logs but i am not able to see logs apart from product updates, so wanted to understand from where i can find that request header ? right now entire FPC is flushing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the default VCL from Magento and have changed TTL to highest in Magento admin, the only plausible explanations of early expired pages would be:

1. Not enough storage allocated to Varnish. That is, a newly cached page will evict another page's cache due to cache storage starvation. To check if such a thing is happening, run `varnishstat` and look for `MAIN.n_lru_nuked`. If it's present and has a non-zero, positive value, it means that more than likely your cache storage size setting for Varnish is not enough to hold all the pages in the cache.
2. *Something* clears up your cache. This may be a custom cron for clearing caches set up by devs, third-party modules with bugs, custom code, etc. Here's for example, [SwissUpLabs SEO module, at some point, did it](https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/magento-2/swissuplabs-themes-and-plugins-for-magento-2-stay-away).

To troubleshoot and find the "something that clears cache", you might have to resort to... not surprisingly, a third-party plugin. The [Full Page Cache Warmer for Magento 2](https://www.getpagespeed.com/recommends/full-page-cache-warmer-magento-2), among its features, has one excellent where you can see the log of cache clears done by Magento code, including plugins. By investigating it, you can find if it's a faulty module that clears cache unnecessarily.

But before you resort to using the mentioned module, you can run the following for some time, e.g. 10 minutes:

```
varnishlog -g request -q 'ReqMethod eq "PURGE" or ReqMethod eq "BAN"'
```

If anything shows up when running this command, you might want to continue with the warmer plugin to investigate what exactly is issuing those requests that result in cleared caches.

Comment: I think you have found the source of the problem. Every couple minutes, a ReqHeader from Amasty comes in and purges the site. Is there some way to block these requests?

Comment: What are `varnishlog` entries for those requests?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: That might be it, but might as well not. If product pages are "tagged" with `amasty_checkbox` by Magento, then yes it would result in clearing cache for all product pages... To make sure, request a product page directly from the backend and examine headers for X-Magento-Tags

Comment: It turns out that one of Amasty's plugins was issuing the purge command every time someone accepted a TOS, which was fairly often. I have varnish ignoring those requests and now varnish is working as intended. Thanks for helping me find the answer.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin can you explain a bit more about this FPC Warmer module? I have installed it and I see there is a section "Cache Flushes" that show the source of flushing cache, but they don't show the "PURGE" request for specific tags to Varnish. Is this what you meant here?

Comment: Hello @DanilaVershinin - I am facing similar issue, can you help me how you have logged those caches ? we tried using amasty warmer extension where i can see the cache logs but i am not able to see logs apart from product updates, so wanted to understand from where i can find that request header ? right now entire FPC is flushing

Comment: @ManthanDave how did you confirm that the whole cache is being flushed? What Amasty plugin show in its log? You can put it on Pastebin for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see some logs and try to determine why the content is only cached for such a short time.

Please run the following command when the cache is empty:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"
```

> I'm assuming the homepage is experiencing this behavior, so I filtered to logs for the `/` URL.

The logging output will explain what is going on and how long a specific response is stored in cache.

### Remove some code from your VCL file

However, I can already spot some strange behavior in you VCL. Take for example the following snippet:

```
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 604800s;
        return (deliver);
    }
```

Please just remove this block of code from you VCL, because it's not doing you any favors.

Setting `beresp.ttl = 0s;` is an absolute no-no. By setting the TTL te zero, your basically taking away any opportunity to leverage the so-called *request coalescing* feature. This feature ensures that multiple simultaneous requests to the same uncached resource are satisfied by a single backend response.

By setting the TTL to zero, you're causing *serialization*. This means that every queued request for that uncached resource is put on the waiting list and processed serially.

Also, marking *private* content as *hit-for-miss* or *hit-for-pass* for *604800 seconds* is not useful either.

The standard logic is in the last *if-statement* in the `vcl_backend_response` subroutine and that will do just fine.

Comment: I updated my question with the varnishlog.